# store multiple pdo connections in an array

Tags: php, pdo

so i have been trying to debug this issue myself for a few days now and i can't seem to figure out why i'm not getting the results I expect.

My code is rather complex and for a DB connection to be establish it spans across 3 Classes and one config file.

but basically my end usage ends up being

`$this->db('test')->query('SELECT * FROM test1');`

this establishes a connection to my database by the alias of `test` the query returns results so i'm good so far.

now my issue is when i try to make a new `PDO` object.

`$this->db('test2')->query('SELECT * FROM test2');`

this returns nothing because there is not table called `test2` in my `test1` object.

but if I do this

`$this->db('test2')->query('SELECT * FROM test1');`

now this returns the same results from the first PDO object.

I have traced and tracked down every line of code to make sure that the correct parameters are being passed to my database class and that each connection is properly established to the corresponding databases.

now my question is, can you have more than one datbase pdo connection? if so is there a special flag that needs to be set in the PDO options? are my connections being cached somewhere and causing this confusion?

this is my PDO declaration in each new class object stored in my array of connections

```
try
        {
            $this->_con = new PDO(
                "mysql:host=" . $host . ";
                 port=" . $port . ";
                 dbname=" . $name, $user, $pass
            );

            $this->_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        } catch(PDOException $e) {

            // TODO: push all $e methods to the developer debugger
            echo "Database Error: ". $e->getMessage();
        }
```

edit my code that uses the connection

step 1: a call to the parent class

```
public function __call($name, $params)
        {
            $class = $name . '_system_helper';
            $hash  = md5($class . $params);

            if (class_exists($class))
            {
                if (!array_key_exists($hash, $this->_sys_helper))
                {
                    if (method_exists($class, 'init'))
                    {
                        $this->_sys_helper[$hash] = call_user_func_array(array($class, 'init'), $params);

                    } else {

                        $this->_sys_helper[$hash] = call_user_func_array($class, $params);
                    }
                }

                return $this->_sys_helper[$hash];
            }

            return null;
        }
```

step 2: called from the parent class

```
class DB_System_Helper extends Jinxup
    {
        private $_con = null;

        public function __construct($end = null)
        {
            $mode = null;
            $host = null;
            $name = null;
            $user = null;
            $pass = null;
            $port = null;

            if (isset($this->config['database']['mode']))
            {
                $mode = $this->config['database']['mode'] == 'production' ? 'production' : 'development';

                if (count($this->config['database'][$mode]) > 1)
                {
                    foreach ($this->config['database'][$mode] as $key => $database)
                    {
                        if ($database['@attr']['alias'] == $end)
                        {
                            $host = $this->config['database'][$mode][$key]['host'];
                            $name = $this->config['database'][$mode][$key]['name'];
                            $user = $this->config['database'][$mode][$key]['user'];
                            $pass = $this->config['database'][$mode][$key]['pass'];
                            $port = $this->config['database'][$mode][$key]['port'];
                        }
                    }

                } else {

                    $host = $this->config['database'][$mode]['host'];
                    $name = $this->config['database'][$mode]['name'];
                    $user = $this->config['database'][$mode]['user'];
                    $pass = $this->config['database'][$mode]['pass'];
                    $port = $this->config['database'][$mode]['port'];
                }

                $this->_con = new PDO_Database_Helper($host, $name, $user, $pass, $port);

            } else {

                echo 'No database mode specified';
            }
        }

        public function __call($name, $param)
        {
            return call_user_func_array(array($this->_con, $name), $param);
        }
    }
```

step 3: called from DB_System_Helper

```
class PDO_Database_Helper extends Jinxup
{
    private $_con = null;
    private $_id  = 0;

    public function __construct($host, $name, $user, $pass, $port = 3306)
    {
        try
        {
            $this->_con = new PDO(
                "mysql:host=" . $host . ";
                 port=" . $port . ";
                 dbname=" . $name, $user, $pass
            );

            $this->_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        } catch(PDOException $e) {

            // TODO: push all $e methods to the developer debugger
            echo "Database Error: ". $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

        [...]
}
```

Comment: In a framework I maintain I allow for and utilize multiple database connections using PDO - it's entirely possible, and quite handy for logging errors (error log inserts don't get rolled back accidentally when the main connection has a rollback).  It would be helpful to see a bit more of your `$this->db( 'name' )` method.

Comment: I'm really wondering if you're getting tripped up because of object references.  This is an interesting approach - quite novel.  How are you using the private $_con member variable?

Comment: not that it will do you much good: http://code.google.com/p/tgsf/source/browse/trunk#trunk%2Ftgsf_core%2Flibraries%2Fdb I create database connection objects in my config files, using an alias - each connection then becomes a self-contained object that is held in an associative array (key is the connection alias name)  When I want to create a new query object, I pass the connection name to its constructor - the query object retrieves the connection object from a global singleton-style function named DBM() and uses it when it needs to communicate with the database.

Comment: so in config: `dbm()->useSetup( array( 'main' => new dbSetup( 'user', 'pass', 'db-name' ) );`  Then, `query::factory( 'main' )->select()->from( 'login' )->exec()->fetchAll();`

Comment: I don't understand how this works. __call and call_user_func_array should be case-sensitive. Calling $this->db('dbname') in your examples at the top shouldn't work, as that would look for 'db_System_Helper' rather than 'DB_System_Helper'. Maybe try $this->DB('dbname')?

Comment: they aren't case sensitive, you can call classes and methods either way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the hashing you're doing is enough to "namespace" each connection in the `$this->_sys_helper` array?

I suspect the problem lies in the first stage.

```
    public function __call($name, $params)
    {
        $class = $name . '_system_helper';
        $hash  = md5($class . $params);

        if (class_exists($class))
        {
            if (!array_key_exists($hash, $this->_sys_helper))
            {
                if (method_exists($class, 'init'))
                {
                    $this->_sys_helper[$hash] = call_user_func_array(array($class, 'init'), $params);

                } else {

                    $this->_sys_helper[$hash] = call_user_func_array($class, $params);
                }
            }

  >>>>>>>>>>>>>> are you sure this is not returning the wrong
  >>>>>>>>>>>>>> connection because of how the hashing is working?
            return $this->_sys_helper[$hash];
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: i don't have that many helper files for there to be a collision somewhere. But i'm thinking that you are right I might be tripping up on the object referencing somewhere.

Comment: I think it's more likely that you are trying to create 2 different helpers with different setup data - the object type is the same - but you need to make sure it's coming out of your array correctly.

Comment: ya hashes match, i did look thru and made sure that i was being returned the correct object. was the first thing i looked at. The issue was that my code was created to only have one db connection, but since found i needed more connections so i adapted the code to allow for more objects being stored by aliases

Comment: are you sure that your db setup is correct?  `if ($database['@attr']['alias'] == $end)`  you don't have repeated alias values do you?

Comment: no but i just passed the alias name over to a public variable and did a vardump each time i call a db object and it seems that my aliases are being crossed somehow. thanks for the idea! thanks for your framework link, i'll commit and push my latest copy after i fix this issue over to my github and send you the link to learn from.